# Batch file that can index and rename files in multiple subfolders, resetting the index every time the loop goes into a new folder

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am in the process of writing a batch file that can quickly run through a root folder, We'll just say "C:\SomeMusic\" that has a lot of subfolders and files in it. What I'm looking to do is to rename **just** the files in each folder, but in a sequential way (ex. somefile1.ext, somefile2.ext ...)

I have this right now, but I do not know how to reset my counter if the loop goes into a new directory

```
SET COUNT=0
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /R %%X IN (*.mp3) DO (
    SET /A COUNT=!COUNT!+1
    SET FN=%%~nxX
    ECHO Renamed "!FN!" to "song!COUNT!.mp3"
    REN %%X song!COUNT!.mp3
)
:EOF
endlocal
PAUSE
```

On a quick sidenote: If I run the Rename command like this, it will name the files "song1.mp3", "song2.mp3" "song3.mp3" regardless of what their name used to be?

Comment: On your sidenote: Of course it will. You said `REN %%X song!COUNT!.mp3`, which hard-codes the name to `song` + the count + `.mp3`. The batch file is doing exactly what you told it to do. Perhaps you meant to use `!FN!!COUNT!.mp3` instead of `song!COUNT!.mp3`?

Comment: Sorry to not be clear on that: !FN! is just there to show the filename of the files that were renamed, giving the user a bit of understanding as to what happened.

Comment: That doesn't change my comment. :-) The batch file is *still* doing exactly what you told it to do - renaming `%%X` to `song!COUNT!`, which explains why every file is being renamed `song` something 
"regardless of what their name used to be" - you've hard-coded `song` as the beginning of each name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to keep track of the current directory, and reset the counter every time it changes:

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /R %%X IN (*.mp3) DO (
    IF NOT "%%~dpX"=="!LASTPATH!" (SET /A COUNT=0) ELSE (SET /A COUNT=!COUNT!+1)
    SET LASTPATH=%%~dpX
    REN "%%X" song!COUNT!.mp3
)
endlocal
```

Note that the resultant filename will be `songX.mp3`. If you need the file to maintain its original name, use this rename code:

```
REN "%%X" "%%~nX!COUNT!%%~xX"
```