# Rename large amount of files using a counter loop within subfolders with a batch file - Windows 7

Tags: windows, batch-file, file-rename, batch-rename

In Windows 7, I have a folder which only contains subfolders and no files.  Within the subfolders, I have a bunch of .dcm files (medical images).  The files within each subfolder have the same name, and I want them to all have different names, more specifically, I want the names to be order 1.dcm, 2.dcm, 3.dcm, etc.

**Current situation**: 
Folders A, B, and C, and each folder contains File1.dcm, File2.dec, File3.dcm
**Would like to have this**:
Folder A contains files 1.dcm, 2.dcm, 3.dcm
Folder B contains files 4.dcm, 5.dcm, 6.dcm
Folder C contains files 7.dcm, 8.dcm, 9.dcm

Is there a way to write a batch file that goes into each subfolder in order and renames the files in numerical order?  I am very much the novice when it comes to writing script for Windows and have no idea how to go about doing this.  I found code that changes file extensions within subfolders, but nothing that does what I am looking for.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch file that can index and rename files in multiple subfolders, resetting the index every time the loop goes into a new folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15375123/batch-file-that-can-index-and-rename-files-in-multiple-subfolders-resetting-the)

Comment: @KenWhite, this does not seem to be a duplicate as it is the opposite here -- *not* to reset the index...

Comment: Yes, there is a way, but you need to do your own research, because StackOverflow is not a free code writing service! Please read the [tour] and learn [ask]! How do you want the files and folders to be sorted? alphabetically or alphanumerically, or just random?

Comment: @aschipfl: It's the same. The poster just needs to remove the code that resets the index if that's not what is wanted. Iterating through folders and renaming files is the same, however, and it makes a good starting point for the poster to make an effort himself instead of just posting *plz givez me teh codez*.

Comment: @KenWhite thank you for pointing me in the right direction, I will give it a read over and try to figure it out.

Comment: @aschipfl I apologize for just asking for the code.  I am a graduate student and am trying to make my life easier in doing my work.  I wish I had the time to learn this coding, but right now I must focus on my Matlab coding.

Comment: Fine, but then you are wrong here. This is a question and answer site for programmers, not a place for requesting code. Once you find the time for trying to code it yourself, come back here and ask a specific question, then we are glad to be of service...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Echo off
For /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%A in (
  'Dir /B/S/ON/A-D "X:\path\to\folder\*.dcm" ^|findstr /N /V "^$"'
) Do Echo Ren "%%~fB" "%%A%%~xB"
```

If the output seems ok remove the echo in the last line.
If you have numbers with different length in one folder be aware that sorting by name will have 10 before 2.

---

For better understanding some explanations:

Dir /B/S/ON/A-D "X:\path\to\folder*.dcm"
  /**B**are format
  /**S**ubdtree recurse
  /**O**rder by **N**ame
  /**A**ttribute **-**(not) **D**irectory

Findstr /N /V "^$"
  /**N**umber each output line delimit with a colon.
  /in**V**erse the match
  **"^$"** a **Reg**ular **Ex**pression meaning an empty line
    ^ matches the begin of a line
    $ matches the end of a line

For /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%A in ('command') do
  Parses output of 'comand' into tokens 1=%%A and *=rest into %%B
  the delimiter **:** is only used for token 1,
  token 2 takes the rest of the line (important to preserve the drive colon)

The vars %%A and %%B are passed to the do (part)

The for vars can be modfied with ~ modifiers see `For /?`
  %%~fB    ~f meaning fullname including dirve and path,
  %%A%%~xB ~x is the extension from %%~xB including the dot

Comment: thank you very much for your help here.  This is exactly what I wanted.  I will go through this and figure out what it is doing so that I learn how the code works and can do this stuff on my own next time.  Thanks!

Comment: @RobCarey Added  some explanantions for better understanding.